# Why would Rails give me a 'mass-assignment security error' on a non-existent attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My `Client` model has `attr_accessible` like this:

```
attr_accessible :email, :firm_id, :name, :phone, :last_contact
```

Then I have this callback:

```
after_save :set_score
```

Then this is the `set_score` method (truncated for brevity):

```
private

def set_score
    score = Score.find_or_create_by_user_id(:user_id => user.id)
    client = self
    firm = self.firm

    days_since_last_contact = (Date.today - client.last_contact).to_i

    score.update_attributes(:firm_size => self.firm_size, :days_since_last_contact => days_since_last_contact)                      

end
```

This is the error I get:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in ClientsController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: days_since_last_contact

app/models/client.rb:124:in `set_score'
app/controllers/clients_controller.rb:67:in `block in create'
app/controllers/clients_controller.rb:66:in `create'
```

The `line 124` is the `score.update_attributes...` line above.

I have no protected attribute called `days_since_last_contact`. That is a local variable that is a result of the `Date` calculation.

Thoughts about what may be happening here?

**Edit 1:**

`Score`'s  attributes accessible whitelist:

```
attr_accessible :client_id, :days_since_contact....
```

Comment: Would be useful to see the Score model here.

If `days_since_last_contact` is a local variable in your model, you certainly can't set it through the `update_attributes` function...so I have a feeling I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: But you're trying to set it as an attribute, so it's not just a local variable, or your code is incorrect.

Comment: It is an attribute on my `Score` model - which is set by the `score = Score.find_or_create...` statement. So, in theory, I am doing `Score.update_attribute(:days_since_last_contact => days_since_last_contact)`

Comment: In that case, the code in question (that would be of interest here) is in `models/score.rb`.  Can you post that up here?

Comment: Would guess that you need to add it to the `attr_accessible` line in your score model.

Comment: Hrmm...you guys are absolutely right. I looked over my `Score` model, and the correct attribute name is `days_since_contact` not `days_since_last_contact`. My bad. It works now. If someone writes that as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute name in your model is not present.  Either you mistyped it, or your code is wrong.

As you state, the name of the attribute in the model is `days_since_contact`, not `days_since_last_contact`, so fixing that should resolve your problem. :)